# How to rewrite URL which has multiple get parameters in Nginx server?

Tags: php, nginx, server, url-rewriting

I am working on a new game development. First of all I want to talk about my URL structure.

```
domain.com/character.php  
domain.com/character.php?id=1

domain.com/character.php?id=1page=slog
domain.com/character.php?page=slog

domain.com/character.php?page=slog&date=4-2018
domain.com/character.php?id=1&page=slog&date=4-2018

domain.com/character.php?id=1&page=slog&sid=10
domain.com/character.php?page=slog&sid=10
```

I want to change my url structure like that:

```
domain.com/character/  
domain.com/character/1

domain.com/character/1/slog
domain.com/character/slog

domain.com/character/slog/date/4-2018
domain.com/character/1/slog/date/4-2018

domain.com/character/1/slog/sid/10
domain.com/character/slog/sid/10
```

Then that purpose I wrote a code something like that to nginx server config. But this is just for character.php and its sub-pages. I will add other versions of it for place.php, company.php etc. Is there any short way to do this instead of:

```
location = /character {
try_files character.php /character.php;
}

location = /character/ {
try_files character.php /character.php;
}

location ~ /character/([0-9]+)$ {
try_files character.php /character.php?id=$1;
}

location ~ /character/([A-z]+)$ {
try_files character.php /character.php?page=$1;
}

location ~ /character/([0-9]+)/([A-z]+)$ {
try_files character.php /character.php?id=$1&page=$2;
}

location ~ /character/([0-9]+)/([A-z]+)/date/(.*)$ {
try_files character.php /character.php?id=$1&page=$2&date=$3;
}

location ~ /character/([A-z]+)/date/(.*)$ {
try_files character.php /character.php?page=$1&date=$2;
}

location ~ /character/([0-9]+)/([A-z]+)/sid/([0-9]+)$ {
try_files character.php /character.php?id=$1&page=$2&sid=$3;
}

location ~ /character/([A-z]+)/sid/([0-9]+)$ {
try_files character.php /character.php?page=$1&sid=$2;
}

location ~ /character/([A-z]+)/action/([A-z]+)/sid/([0-9]+)$ {
try_files character.php /character.php?page=$1&action=$2&sid=$3;
}
```

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

Using nginx configuration for this purpose seems pretty unorthodox. You should be routing URLs on your PHP application level, since nginx can already handle such requests with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`.

You should look into [how to route URLs like that in PHP](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/) using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.